# Where caching should happen in Reactive Programming?

Tags: java, reactive-programming

In our (testing) code, we need to cache (thus not purely functional) the events before transforming it into another Entity and persist it in `subscribe`. Here is the sample code:

```
Observable<Integer> ids                         = Observable.range(1, 3);
Observable<String> references                   = Observable.just("REF1", "REF2", "REF3");
Observable<TransactionStatus> statusObservable  = Observable.just(CANCELLED, PAID, PAID);

Observable
    .zip(ids, references, statusObservable, (id, ref, status) -> {
        // Where shall this logic be put in?
        redisCachingService.cacheForPpdl(GROUP_ID, ref, status);
        return new StatusUpdateBuilder()
                .withId(id)
                .withRef(ref)
                .withStatus(status)
                .build();
        }
    )
    .subscribe(update -> {
        repository.save(update);
    });
```

I have been struggling with where I should call `redisCachingService.cacheForPpdl(GROUP_ID, ref, status);`.

Comment: Why are those `Observables`? Are they coming in as an event stream in the real app? If so, you could `zip` them, then do the caching in a `do` or `tap` then perform the final transformation in a `map` with `StatusBuilder`.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes , those Observables are used to prepare testing data. They are kind of from nowhere in the testing context.